# python Pyodbc, cant create a field named "Date" in the table

Tags: python, windows, ms-access, pyodbc

The problem is that I can't create a field named `Date` (I think because its a type)
Any ideas how to do that?

```
from pyodbc import connect
# database connect
conn = connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=test.mdb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
# sql query execute
query = "create table MyTable(name varchar(30), age integer , Date date)"
cursor.execute(query)
# commit changes             
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Path\to\myscript\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query)
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in field definition. (-3553) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Environment: Windows 7 64bit, Python 2.7 pyodbc-3.0.6.win-amd64-py2.7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DATE` is a [reserved word](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in Access (and other software).

Try wrapping the `Date` column name with square brackets `[]`, or better yet, come up with a different column name.

```
...
query = "create table MyTable(name varchar(30), age integer , [Date] date)"
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Surround the name in backticks the ` symbol. But, I would highly suggest changing the name to something else to prevent typos from happening.

Comment: Doesn't MSFT Access use brackets `[]`?

Comment: Yes , thats it ! brackets were missing

Comment: Oh, totally missed the MSFT part.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you can't create a column with the same name as type. Some RDBMS's will allow you to do this if you quote it, i.e. "`..age integer, "Date" date)`" (or as others have said, backticks or square brackets) but then you have to quote it in all your queries as well. Better to avoid that.

Note that this isn't a python problem, it's a problem with the database server (which appears to be MS Access). (And to be accurate, it's not a *problem* with the database server, that's just how it works. It just has nothing to do with python.)

Comment: Thanks for answer , Yeah, i trie that before !
any other way? because a could create the field 'Date' when using MS Access  ! 
but from python i can't ?!

Comment: Using a table designer in Access? It put the brackets in for you.

Comment: Yep! that's what i thought !